# How to copy one folder into multiple folders in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-tool

This is the issue. I have a folder named `Covers` which is in another folder named `Folder A`. I have to copy the `Covers` folder from `Folder A` to all the sub-folders of another folder named `Folder B`. There are hundreds of sub-folders in `Folder B`. How can I do it through command line in windows or even power-shell.

Here is the folder structure:

| Folder A | Folder B |
| --- | --- |
| Covers | Sub-Folder 1 |
|  | Sub-Folder 2 |
|  | Sub-Folder 3 |
|  | Sub-Folder 4 |

The path of the `FolderA` is `D:\AJ\Desktop\FolderA` and the path of `FolderB` is `D:\AJ\Desktop\FolderB`.

I am trying to copy `Covers` folder from `FolderA` to all the sub-folders of `FolderB`.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it simply means (from the tooltip) "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: @AaronJones - I did not down-vote you.

Comment: @MarkTolonen

How do I find out who down-voted me and I would also like to know what kind of research should I have put in the question ? Again, just trying to learn how to be efficient here, so please be patient with me.

Comment: @Enigmativity

Sorry, you edited my question so I assumed that you did. Anyways, you seem to be very experienced here, so, I would like to know if I have committed any mistakes while asking the question?

Comment: Take the [Tour], read [ask].  You can't tell who downvotes to prevent revenge downvoting (I assume).  Showing a coding attempt, even if it doesn't work, shows research effort.  Type `help` in the command shell lists commands you can use, and `/?` on most commands gives help about the command as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @MarkTolonen

Revenge Downvoting? Haha. But, I would have just asked what I did wrong from that person. Thanks for the links. I will go through them to learn more regarding how to better ask questions. Also, I had no clue as to how to do it in command line so I could not post even a wrong attempt. Anyways, thanks for all the clarifications and your patience.

Comment: @AaronJones - Nonetheless, being a new member doesn't mean that we should down-vote you any less. If the question is of poor quality then it deserves a down-vote. It's how you learn to post better questions. If we didn't do it then you wouldn't have the opportunity to learn. Think of down-votes as a learning opportunity, not a criticism.

Comment: @Enigmativity

You are right. That helps. Thank you.

Comment: @AaronJones - Now I've got some direct feedback. Please don't edit to question to ask follow up questions - especially those from answers. We're trying to get good, clean questions and the associated answers. By changing the question you prevent getting alternative answers that may be equally good. If you have questions about an answer, then pop those questions in the comments of the answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity

I updated the question as the question was not asked properly (my fault) as I have been told multiple times. I updated only the part which contained the 'wrong code' I was using. But, after your edit, the question clearly looks more clean. I will not alter it. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Enigmativity Except the original question didn't have enough information, and now it is still incorrect.  The attempt and error message were needed to figure out the correct answer.  Turns out the directories have spaces in them.

Comment: @AaronJones - It looked like the code you added was from Mark Tolonen's answer. You didn't have that code when you originally asked your question. Is that right?

Comment: @Enigmativity

Yes, that is indeed true but it was pointed out to me by Mark himself to update the question with the code I am trying and also post any errors I am receiving. The comment section was getting longer so updating the question seemed like a better move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.  Use `for /?` to see the help for the command.  `/d` means wildcards match directories, so it loops through the folders under `FolderB` and copies the files.  `xcopy /?` will show that `/sei` will assume the destiniation is a directory and copy subdirectories including empty ones, to make sure everything under `Covers` gets copied.  Use the `cd` command to start in the initial directory containing the folders:

```
cd /d d:\aj\desktop
for /d %i in (FolderB\*) do @xcopy "FolderA\Covers" "%i\Covers" /sei
```

Comment: Will this work even if the Covers folder is empty. Also, could you show me how to copy the 'Covers' folder without its contents into the sub-folders of 'Folder B'.

Comment: You said you wanted to copy it.  Use `@md %i\Covers` instead of the `@xcopy` to just make a Covers directory.

Comment: It is not working. I am using windows terminal. Also tried in command line as well.

Comment: @AaronJones Now that you have a starting point, edit your question with your code attempt and show any error messages.  "It is not working" doesn't give me a clue what you did wrong.  Make your question as clear as possible about exactly what you want and what you've attempted.

Comment: Okay, I will do just that.

Comment: Updated the question. Please check and help.

Comment: @AaronJones I’m still guessing as you didn’t show the command promt or error messages, but you do have to start in the right folder.

Comment: No, I did start the command promt in the desktop location. 

I am getting error:

"Invalid number of parameters" multiple times. Sorry, I forgot to post the error message above. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @AaronJones Are there spaces in the names? Add quotes and make sure the folder names are correctly specified if spaces are involved (answer updated).  Also, this hand-holding is why these "simple" questions get downvoted.  Read a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_files.htm).

Comment: The new code works. And yes, the sub folder names had spaces in them. Thank you. One last question, suppose, I want to make a directory named 'Covers' in all the sub-folders of 'FolderB', how should I go about it?

Comment: @AaronJones I answered that in the 2nd comment above.  See if you can figure it out 

Comment: Already did.
==> for /d %i in (FolderB\*) do @md "%i\Covers"

Thanks for all the help and patience. Cheers brother.